# Online browsing of node-webkit

Tags: github, node-webkit

I am reading this [link](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/How-node.js-is-integrated-with-chromium). and want to have a look at the files that it is referring to, online.

Where are chromium and node source codes of node-webkit, on the github or some_where else ?

I looked at [zcbenz](https://github.com/zcbenz/chromium/tree/master/)  but i could not find file `third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/bindings/v8/V8DOMWindowShell.cpp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find it in [.DEPS.git](https://github.com/zcbenz/chromium/blob/node/.DEPS.git).